Mutating table error on after statement trigger. Why?
Imagine the following scenario in Oracle 19:
Table A
Table B
Table B has a compound trigger TB_TRG that reads Table A (procedure fired after statement).
Table A has a trigger that updates Table B (and so fires TB_TRG).
I get the mutating table A error. Shouldn't it be avoided since I am reading table A in a AFTER STATEMENT call?
Thanks
I built a compound trigger where it reads Table A in a procedure called from an after statement clause. The mutating error persists.

--  DDL for Table DEPT
CREATE TABLE "DEPT" 
("DEPTNO" NUMBER(2,0), 
 "DNAME" VARCHAR2(14), 
 "LOC" VARCHAR2(13), 
 "SAL_FACTOR" NUMBER(4,0)
 );


--  DDL for Index SYS_C0031557
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "SYS_C0031557" ON "DEPT" ("DEPTNO") 
;


--  DDL for Trigger DEPT_TRG1
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER "DEPT_TRG1" 
before insert or update on dept
for each row

begin

if :new.deptno is null then
  select dept_seq.nextval into :new.deptno from sys.dual;
end if;

if :new.sal_factor is not null then
    update emp set new_sal = sal * :new.sal_factor where deptno = :new.deptno;
else
    update emp set new_sal = null where deptno = :new.deptno;
end if;

end;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "DEPT_TRG1" ENABLE;


--  Constraints for Table DEPT
ALTER TABLE "DEPT" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("DEPTNO")
USING INDEX  ENABLE;


--  DDL for Table EMP
CREATE TABLE "EMP" 
("EMPNO" NUMBER(4,0), 
 "ENAME" VARCHAR2(10), 
 "JOB" VARCHAR2(9), 
 "MGR" NUMBER(4,0), 
 "HIREDATE" DATE, 
 "SAL" NUMBER(7,2), 
 "COMM" NUMBER(7,2), 
 "DEPTNO" NUMBER(2,0), 
 "NEW_SAL" NUMBER(7,0), 
 "DEPT_SAL_FACTOR" NUMBER(4,0)
 );


--  DDL for Index SYS_C0031556
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "SYS_C0031556" ON "EMP" ("EMPNO") 
;


--  DDL for Trigger EMP_TRG2
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER "EMP_TRG2" 
for insert or update on emp
compound trigger
          
deptno# dept.deptno%type;


after each row is

begin

    deptno# := :new.deptno;

end after each row;

after statement is

    factor# number(4);

begin

     select sal_factor
       into factor#
      from dept where deptno = deptno#;

end after statement;
          
end;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "EMP_TRG2" ENABLE;


--  DDL for Trigger EMP_TRG1
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER "EMP_TRG1" 
          before insert or update on emp
          for each row
          
          
          begin
              if :new.empno is null then
                  select emp_seq.nextval into :new.empno from sys.dual;
             end if;
             
             
             
             
          end;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "EMP_TRG1" ENABLE;


--  Constraints for Table EMP
ALTER TABLE "EMP" MODIFY ("EMPNO" NOT NULL ENABLE);
ALTER TABLE "EMP" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("EMPNO")
USING INDEX  ENABLE;


--  Ref Constraints for Table EMP
ALTER TABLE "EMP" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("DEPTNO")
  REFERENCES "DEPT" ("DEPTNO") ENABLE;
ALTER TABLE "EMP" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("MGR")
  REFERENCES "EMP" ("EMPNO") ENABLE;


--  The DML:
update dept set sal_factor = 4 where deptno = 40;


--  The Error:
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
update dept set sal_factor = 4 where deptno = 40
Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 47
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-04091: table SETICIS.DEPT is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "SETICIS.EMP_TRG2", line 20
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SETICIS.EMP_TRG2'
ORA-06512: at "SETICIS.DEPT_TRG1", line 8
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SETICIS.DEPT_TRG1'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
       this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
       in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.


Please [edit] the question and provide a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and CREATE TRIGGER statements for your tables and triggers; the INSERT statements for your sample data in those tables; the INSERT or UPDATE statement that you are using to trigger the error; the full error message; an English (not code) explanation of the logic you are trying to implement; and the expected output. At the moment your question is not answerable because it contains no code and no way of reproducing the problem.

Please add also the DML statement and exact error message.

As requested. Thanks

If trigger A updates B and trigger B attempts to read from A, you will get a mutating error. Within the context of a trigger you cannot read from a table being modified within that execution scope (the originating row update operation) because A is in the process of being modified, so in an in-between state. You'll have to remove your query of table A from trigger B.

Hi. Ok, I understand that. But isn't this the purpose of using compound triggers, and an after statement clause? What you have described is the exact definition of the mutating table error.

@CInglez, you will need to provide your table and trigger definition to get any further help. Without seeing code, we can only provide generalities.

Ok, here is an example, I think I did not understand the whole point of compound triggers:

If I update table DEPT, there is the mutating table error.

The problem here was the trigger on DEPT. This one should be a compound trigger, not only the trigger on EMP. Problem solved.
